# Is it valid to use probabilistic methods on convex polygons?

Tags: combinatorics, convex-geometry, random-graphs, convex-hulls

I am working on convex polygons & algorithms among points in general position and I'm wondering if it's valid approach to the problem using probabilty or randomness. Let me explain briefly.

Let's assume $V$  is a set $n$ points in a general-position (no three pionts on the same line). Then, choose a random ordered subset $X$ of these points  $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3,… ,x_k)$ to form a polygon. For each edge of the polygon, namely consecutive pair of points $e_i = (x_i,x_{i+1})$, if all the points in $X-\{x_i,x_{i+1}\}$ are on the either side of the edge then $X$ is in convex position.
Let's denote the probabilty of having this case for first edge as $p_1$ which is easy to evaluate for sufficently large n.
$$p_1 \to \frac{1}{2^{k-3}}+$$ But since the valid side of the other edges is set, then for the remaining cases
for  $i >1$, $$P_i \to \frac{1}{2^{(k-2)}}$$ according to my observation.

Please also note that  for any $j < i$,  $p_i$ and $p_j$ are independent events from each other. When we try to compute the conditional probability I observe that  $$p_1 \cap p_2 \cap ... \cap p_{i-1} |  p_i =  p_i$$.  What I mean is that, assuming that all $p_1,..,p_i$ are holds then the the problem remains same, that is in the worst case halving the remaining points. In this iterative random process each edge divides the remaning points as valid ones and invalid ones.Then the probability of having $X$ in convex position is, let's say $p_X$

$$p_X = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^{k} p_{i}     \to \frac{1}{2^{(k-3)+(k-2)(k-1)}} $$

The number of distinct $k$ ordered subset in $n$ points is exactly $\frac{P(n,k)}{k}$. So the expected number of valid $X$ convexes in $n$ points is
$$E_{convex(n,k)} \to \frac{P(n,k)}{k.2^{(k-2)k-1}} $$

it is easy to see that

$$ n > 2^{k-2}+k/2 -1  \implies E_{convex(n,k)} > 1 $$

This is the point I got stuck. Is that result really implies the existence of convex polygon at given conditions above?

Hopefully I'm not mixing apples and oranges.

Comment: There seems to be an issue already with your computation of the probabilities $p_i$. This probability depends on the structure of the underlying point set. For example, there are two ways to place 4 points in general position: either you have a triangular convex hull with the fourth point in the interior, or all four points are on the convex hull. Computing $p_1$ for $k=4$ in both cases gives 1/2 for the first configuration and 2/3 for the second.

Comment: Dear Patrick, you are absolutely right. I should have added two remarks. First , n is suffciently large than k and the second is $p_i$ is larger than 1/2 and at the worst case converges to the 1/2.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something, but I still don‘t think this is true: computing $p_1$ for points in convex position, I get $2/(k-1)$, which is smaller than 1/2 for almost all values of k.

Comment: Actually for a given random edge, i.e. a node pair, in worst case the set of points divided into halves in either sides. That means, the probability is, number of k-2 ordered sets obeying the condition, which is approximately $P((n-2)/2,k-2) + P((n-2)/2,k-2)$. and divided by number of all possbile ordered sets which is $P(n-2,k-2)$. This number should converge 1/2

Comment: According to my computations, this number converges to 2^(3-k).

Comment: Yes. You are correct. Then repeating for all edges assuming that they are independent events. the number should converge.  $2^{k.(3-k)}$

Comment: I see, now I get that p_i>1/(2^(k-3)). My next issue is the independence, why should all those events be independent? In particular, to conclude that the probability of all events is just the product of the probabilities, pairwise independence is not sufficient.

Comment: Btw, as I only asked annoying questions so far: I like the approach! And the probabilistic method has certainly been used with success in discrete geometry before :)

Comment: Dear Patrick, I have two points to clarify.
First, As you mentioned clearly $p_1 \to \frac{1}{2^{(k-3)}}$  because either side of the first edge is valid. But since the valid side of the other edges is set, then for the remaining cases
for  $i >1$, $P_i \to \frac{1}{2^{(k-2)}}$ according to my observation.

Comment: Second, when I try to compute the conditional probablity I observe that  $p_1,p_2,p_{i-1} |  p_i =  p_i$.  What I mean is that, assuming that all $p_1,..,p_i$ are true then the the problem remains same, that is in the worst case halving the remaining points. In this iterative random process each edge divides the remaning points as valid ones and invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

The method seems valid. But after careful consideration, nearly all $p_i$ pairs are interdependent, clearly limiting each other's result set. Unfortunately the result is not valid.